# scrollIntoView not woring in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a online shopping website, and I want to use anchor to scroll website to specific position.

My code is like:

```
product_menu = () => {
    let product_data = this.state.product_data;

    return (
      <ul className="product-menu-category scroll-x" id="Product_Category_Area">
        {
          product_data.map((product_column, index) => {
            return product_column.data.map((product_block, index2) => {
              if(index == 0 && index2 == 0) {
                return <li className="active" data-id={product_block.category_sid} onClick={() => this.scrollToAnchor(product_block.category_code)}><a class="nav-link" href="#">{product_block.category_name}</a></li>
              }else {
                return <li data-id={product_block.category_sid} onClick={() => this.scrollToAnchor(product_block.category_code)}><a class="nav-link" href="#">{product_block.category_name}</a></li>
              }
            })
          })
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }

product = () => {
    let product_data = this.state.product_data;

    return (
      <div id="Product_Menu_Area">
        {
          product_data.map((product_column, product_column_key) => {
            return <div key={product_column_key} className="product-column">
              {
                product_column.data.map((product_block, product_block_key) => {
                  return <div className="product-block" id="" key={product_column_key + '-' + product_block_key}>
                  //...
```

and the scroll function be like:

```
scrollToAnchor = (anchorName) => {
  let anchorElement = document.getElementById(anchorName);

  if (anchorElement) {
    anchorElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end' })
  }
}
```

but it is not working, how should I do?

Comment: You should NOT use `document.getElementById` in React. In this case you can set the scrollbehaviour to `smooth` using CSS. That way you won't need any javascript for scrolling and can just use `<a href="#myanchor">` links.

Comment: What do you mean?? Like use a href in my list component?

Comment: In this case it seems to me that you can include both `<a href="#mylink">go there</a>` and `<a name ="mylink"></a>` in the HTML templates of your components. If that doesn't work out for you, then you could also create `click={...}` handlers, but still not `getElementById`.